# Eavesdropping on COM communication

Tags: c#, api, com, itunes

I have a spesific software that integrates with Itunes using the COM interface. This works very well, but I prefer using another music application with the same features. (That also supports streaming)

The plan is to make a wrapper/adapter that presents itself as itunes and exposes a COM interface towards the mentioned software, and controls my preferred music/library application accordingly (It has a good API).

In order to do that I need to have some more information regarding Itunes COM interface. What would be the best way to expose all traffic through the interface in order to duplicate its behaviour?

I have some programming experience, but never worked with COM before. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Why eavesdrop if you can just read the documentation?

http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html

But first you need to register as a developer [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/)

### Edit

You can try out [ApiMonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) to find out the exact interfaces and methods being used by your app to know which COM interfaces to implement.
But I just googled the app, I didn't use it myself.

Comment: Why make things simple? Thanks for the pointer - I'll have a look

Comment: Had a quick look at the doc. The interface seems quite extensive, and I suspect my software only uses a small subset. So it would still me handy to listen on the communication to identify which is actually beeing used.

Comment: Oh, you need to know the exact subset it uses, I get it now. I'll think a bit :)

Comment: Thanks for the ApiMonitor link. Looked promising, but turns out it can't hook to .Net applications. Anyway, I'll just go ahead and create a simple interface with static data only, that should not take too long and lets me discover what is actually beeing used. Thanks for your help